# SignalR hangs on foreign keys

Tags: .net, entity-framework, signalr

I have a SignalR server that should transmit `Message` objects from the server to the client. The hub-method looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new PsmContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            return context.Messages
                .Include("Machine")
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Logging.Log(Logging.ServerLog, err);
        return new List<Message>();
    }
}
```

The data is organized in the following way: A `Message` originates from a `Machine`, and a `Machine` is on a `Site`. A `Site` in turn has multiple `Machine`s. This important: Machine has *no navigation property* for the type `Message`, but *`Machine` and `Site` reference each other:*

```
// Machine.cs
public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
public int SiteId { get; set; }

// Site.cs
public virtual ICollection<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
```

When I query the data like I showed above, everything works. But as soon as I add

```
.Include("Machine.Site")
```

the client never gets his anwser (`await HubProxy.Invoke<IEnumerable<Message>>("GetMessages")` hangs forever). The funny thing is, that the hub-method returns - I tested that with log entries. This means, that the failure is somewhere in the internals of SignalR.

I assume, this is because of the `Machine` and `Site` entities referencing each other, causing the serialization of the objects to fail. How can I fix that?

*(The client is a .NET 4.5 client, if that matters, the hub runs in IIS 8.5)*

Comment: have you ever found a solution? I have the same issue. Normal objects are return fine, but if I have navigation property via virtual ICollection the call  await HubProxy.Invoke<bar>("foo") hangs

Comment: I gave up on SignalR then, but IIRC it had to do with serializer settings and loops.

Comment: today I had some luck with :

**var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            serializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
            serializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;** seams to work, I no longer have the hang, but now I have a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException with error ( Self referencing loop detected with type) later in code after the hanging code. I'll look now how I can fix this.

Comment: I recommend to make those settings available with DI so you always use the same ones. Probably you have another place in the code where those settings aren't active.

Comment: no, this is not related to the settings. I need to add **public bool ShouldSerializePROPERTYNAME(){ return false; }**, this fixed my issue with the JsonSerializationException. Now SignalR works fine. your issue was the missing **PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects** setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe serialization is an issue, Newtonsoft.Json has 3 values for reference loop handling:

```
public enum ReferenceLoopHandling
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Throw a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException when a loop is encountered.
        Error = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Ignore loop references and do not serialize.
        Ignore = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Serialize loop references.
        Serialize = 2,
    }
```

So you can change it and testing in Global.Asax / Startup.cs:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error
            };
```

I don't know if this will help you out, but at least you can test to see if serialization is really issue of your problem.

How will you handle the error if it really is up to your design, but I'd go with some view models instead of sending raw entity objects back to the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested all the options, none make any dent on the production server. When I run the server on localhost however, I get a `JsonReaderException` with Message "Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'R[0].Machine.Name', line 1, position 256." and Path="R[0].Machine.Name" using all `ReferenceLoopHandling` flags.

Comment: If a JSON string contains special characters like double quotes ", backslashes \ or slashes /, they need to be escaped with backslashes. Your value there is likely a string containing one of the above characters. This will cause serialization to fail resulting in the exception.

Comment: Hm.. this shouldn't be my job, since it is SignalR that should do that for me. Still, can you point me to how to do that please?